# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_salesforce'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, simple-salesforce

I'm VERY new to python, but am somewhat familiar with Salesforce apex, so I thought I'd start out on a project.

I downloaded simple_salesforce to my raspberry pi, but whenever I try to run the import command so that I can login to Salesforce, it says the module is not found.

Can someone help me on where I'm going wrong? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMKcq.png)

Comment: Try to install your module with `pip3 install <module_name>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't install the module, just downloaded it. Open a terminal and install it using pip:

```
pip install simple-salesforce
```

You might need to change "pip" to "pip3" as you're using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33941246)